# Will a non functional blower keep a gas dryer from heating?

Tags: dryer

Gas dryer quit heating a few days ago.  Took the back off and tested all of the thermostats all good.  The ignition system seems to be working too but haven't gone fully down that road.

DOH!

I see a spindle that screws on the top of my blower and a seemingly brand new looking blower belt...  Sitting on the floor of my dryer.  So I am going to put the belt on (chime in if you know how).

Would the blower not running cause something to shut the heat off?

Kenmore Elite 11077032601.  And the manual sucks so don't need links to that.

Comment: There's usually a thermal fuse/thermostat on the metal baffle above where the flame burns. That baffle likely heats up a lot faster without airflow.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend finding out.  If the thermal fuse does not blow you could have a dangerous concentration of heat.  The blower failed on my dryer while I was out of town.  My daughter kept running it and it caught the wire insulation on fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Without the blower running, the dryer will overheat and shutdown.  Some models may not even fire if the blower is not running, since they may rely on the blower for exhaust flow.

Comment: The pulley that screws on to the top of the fan and the belt that connects it to the motor where just sitting at the bottom of the dryer.  Had to take the whole thing apart to get it back on.  Once back on it has had no issues.  Weird thing is that we noticed it heating clothes worse about 1.5 months ago - so it seems that the heat element was probably running without the fan but finally just quit altogether.  Who knows.  Easier if the dryer had at least some kind of error message.